# Wordpress dashboard + website are totally messed up

Tags: dashboard

I just shifted my website from local host to server.
Everything is messed up in the website and the dashboard. It is just a text in a white background.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet(s) are not being loaded.

1. Check your themes *header.php* and *functions.php* and adjust stylesheet paths
2. Do a hard refresh - Ctrl + F5 (CMD + F5 on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

check `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`

in `wp-admin > Settings > General`